# ajax j query - 2 inserts in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code

```
$('#enviarGuia').click(function () {
    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
    var rut = $('#rut').val()
    var obs = $('#obs').val();
    var direccion = $('#direccion').val();
    var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();
    var total = $('#total').val();
    var sucursal = $('#sucursal').val();
    if (validaSalida()) {
        respuesta = confirm("Esta seguro de guardar?")

        if (respuesta) {
            cargaCorre() // carga correlativo
            var correlativo = $('#correlativo').html();
            $('#tablasDetalle tr').not(':first').each(function () {
                var unidad = $(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").html();
                var descrip = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").html();
                var p_unitario = $(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").html();
                var correlativo = $('#correlativo').html();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
                    data: 'unidad=' + unidad + '&descrip=' + descrip + '&p_unitario=' + p_unitario + '&correlativo=' + correlativo + '&sucursal=' + sucursal,
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function (msg) {

                    }
                })
            })
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
                data: 'fecha=' + fecha + '&rut=' + rut + '&obs=' + obs + '&direccion=' + direccion + '&ciudad=' + ciudad + '&total=' + total + '&sucursal=' + sucursal + '&correlativo=' + correlativo,
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (parseInt(msg) != 5) {
                        if (sucursal == "GE") {
                            top.ifrm.location.href = '../pdf/guia_entrega_pdf.php?numero=' + correlativo + '&tipo=' + sucursal;
                        } else {
                            top.ifrm.location.href = '../pdf/guia_entrega_tarapaca_pdf.php?numero=' + correlativo + '&tipo=' + sucursal;
                        }

                    }

                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is that i have two insert in a function

the first is

```
    $('#tablasDetalle tr').not(':first').each(function() {
var unidad=$(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").html();
var descrip=$(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").html();
var p_unitario=$(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").html();
var correlativo=$('#correlativo').html();

$.ajax({    
  type: "POST",
  url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
  data: 'unidad='+unidad+'&descrip='+descrip+'&p_unitario='+p_unitario+'&correlativo='+correlativo+'&sucursal='+sucursal,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(msg){

  }
      })
})
```

this is the detail of that always is more than one  insert

and the second insert is

```
    $.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
  data: 'fecha='+fecha+'&rut='+rut+'&obs='+obs+'&direccion='+direccion+'&ciudad='+ciudad+'&total='+total+'&sucursal='+sucursal+'&correlativo='+correlativo,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(msg){
  if(parseInt(msg)!=5)
   {
if(sucursal=="GE")
{
 top.ifrm.location.href='../pdf/guia_entrega_pdf.php?numero='+correlativo+'&tipo='+sucursal;
}
else{
    top.ifrm.location.href='../pdf/guia_entrega_tarapaca_pdf.php?numero='+correlativo+'&tipo='+sucursal;
    }

   }

  }
      })
```

this is the head and always is one insert.

the problem is when i show the document in a pdf by php

```
    if(sucursal=="GE")
{
 top.ifrm.location.href='../pdf/guia_entrega_pdf.php?numero='+correlativo+'&tipo='+sucursal;
}
else{
    top.ifrm.location.href='../pdf/guia_entrega_tarapaca_pdf.php?numero='+correlativo+'&tipo='+sucursal;
    }
```

The document shows before the end of the first insertion cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `async: false,` to the options of both of your $.ajax calls. This forces the second ajax requests to wait until the first one ended loading.

Answer (score 1):

Put the second ajax call within success() of the first one. Then you will have a guarantee that it will only run after the first ajax call succeeded. Of course, you only have to do it after you are done with the ajax for the last of your $('#tablasDetaille tr') elements.

```
$('#enviarGuia').click(function(){
    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
    var rut = $('#rut').val()
    var obs = $('#obs').val();
    var direccion = $('#direccion').val();
    var ciudad = $('#ciudad').val();
    var total = $('#total').val();
    var sucursal = $('#sucursal').val();

    if (validaSalida()) {
        respuesta = confirm("Esta seguro de guardar?")
        if (respuesta) {
            cargaCorre() // carga correlativo
            var correlativo = $('#correlativo').html();
            $('#tablasDetalle tr').not(':first').each(function () {
                var unidad = $(this).children("td:nth-child(1)").html();
                var descrip = $(this).children("td:nth-child(2)").html();
                var p_unitario = $(this).children("td:nth-child(3)").html();
                var correlativo = $('#correlativo').html();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
                    data: 'unidad=' + unidad + '&descrip=' + descrip + '&p_unitario=' + p_unitario + '&correlativo=' + correlativo + '&sucursal=' + sucursal,
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (/* do something here to check that you've 
                            processed the last element in $('#tablasDetalle tr')*/)
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "../ajax/registra_guia_entrega.php",
                            data: 'fecha=' + fecha + '&rut=' + rut + '&obs=' + obs + '&direccion=' + direccion + '&ciudad=' + ciudad + '&total=' + total + '&sucursal=' + sucursal + '&correlativo=' + correlativo,
                            datatype: "html",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                if (parseInt(msg) != 5) {
                                    if (sucursal == "GE") {
                                        top.ifrm.location.href = '../pdf/guia_entrega_pdf.php?numero=' + correlativo + '&tipo=' + sucursal;
                                    } else {
                                        top.ifrm.location.href = '../pdf/guia_entrega_tarapaca_pdf.php?numero=' + correlativo + '&tipo=' + sucursal;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                         })
                     }
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```